# Не убираются/заменяются подстроки из строк, выведенных через os.listdir()

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, файлы

```
import os


for x in os.listdir():
    if x.endswith('.session'):
        x.replace('.session', '')
        print(x)

>>> somefile1.session
    somefile2.session
    somefile3.session
```

При исполнении скрипта, строки (наверное, строки) находятся верные, но заменить ненужную часть в них не получается. Пробовал использовать "os.walk()", результат тот же. Подскажите, как решить проблему? Всем добра и развития скилла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы никуда не присваиваете результат замены. Надо присваивать:

```
x = x.replace('.session', '')
```

Comment: Как же это глупо, действительно не заметил, спасибо.

Comment: @ГерманШеич В общем-то это типовая ошибка, часто встречается )